# SignalR connect setup in react- using useEffects

Tags: reactjs, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using  `"@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.5",` and trying to set up a connection.

It is able to connect with the backend, but I am not sure if my setup looks OK for when the connection fails.

Specifically, I am wondering if the last useEffect is correctly written (the placement of the onClose clause)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(
        "https://localhost:3000/workorderHub",
        { accessTokenFactory: () => token, withCredentials: false }
      )
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

    setConnection(newConnection);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function start() {
      if (connection) {
        try {
          connection
            .start()
            .then(() => {
              connection.invoke("SubscribeToProject", projectId); // calling hub method from the client
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err.toString());
            });

          connection.on(
            "OperationUpdated",
            (projectId, operationId, operation) => {
              // function called from the backend Hub
              actions.updateSyncedOperation({ operationId, operation });
            }
          );
        } catch (err) {
          console.log({ err });
          setTimeout(start, 5000);
        }
      } else {
        connection.onclose(async () => {
          await start();
        });
      }
    }
    start();
  }, [connection]);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem correct to me. You can simplify the else branch to `if (!connection) connection.onclose` which will probably result in `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onclose')`. I think you can simplify the code a lot and I don't think you need 2 `useEffect`.

Comment: Hey @meerkat, do you have any update on this? I'm interested to know what you ended up with. I don't see any clean-up return functions in your effects, have you done any testing using `React.StrictMode`  ? Thanks.

Comment: see the newest answer @pmcilreavy

Answer (score 3):

For React 18 with the new strictMode behaviour i do the following.
It only creates one connection without any errors and it seems to cleanup properly during strictmode behaviour.

```js
export const useLiveUpdates = () => {
  const [connectionRef, setConnection] = useState < HubConnection > ();

  function createHubConnection() {
    const con = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${EnvService.getUrlHub('url')}`, {
        accessTokenFactory: () => AuthService.getToken(),
      })
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();
    setConnection(con);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    createHubConnection();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (connectionRef) {
      try {
        connectionRef
          .start()
          .then(() => {
            connectionRef.on('message', () => { ...
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            logger.error(`Error: ${err}`);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error as Error);
      }
    }

    return () => {
      connectionRef ? .stop();
    };
  }, [connectionRef]);
};
```